# How to make math symbols like \prod smaller

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I know this is simple, but I can't seem to find the correct code.
If I have 
`$d \prod$`
how can I make the height of the `\prod` symbol equal to that of `d`?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't `$d\Pi$`?

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you are looking for the greek letter Π, which can be obtained with `\Pi`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  $d\;\Pi$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that it’s common to set the `d` upright if it’s belongs to an integral or differential operation, i.e. `\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x`. You may define a new command `\diff` as `\newcommand\dd{\,\mathrm{d}}` and use `\int f(x) \dd x`.

Comment: @Tobi,that depends on tradition. I do not know many mathematicians who use upright 'd' (me neither). But several physicists do

Comment: @daleif: I'm a physicist ;-) I prefer the upright version to differentiate between variable _d_ and integral d. But I see many italic d's, and I guess that's because the tutors who write the excersies are too lazy … :-)

Comment: I think it is also esthetics. I think it looks strange